# Update text from variable using a common function javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a common function that can be call in html so I can update the value from variable.

```
function getActivityPoint(activityName) {
   document.getElementsByClassName('share_points')[0].innerHTML = activityName;
}
```

my variable

```
var ap = {
   'movie_review':'20',
}
```

And in HTML I would like to do this.

```
<div class="share_points" onload="getActivityPoint(ap.movie_review)">-</div>
<div class="share_points" onload="getActivityPoint(ap.game_review)">-</div>
.............
```

Comment: So...what's the problem?

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline **onload** event does not work for a div.

You may change your code in order to change your divs, using data attributes, like:

```
<div class="share_points" data-load="movie_review">-</div>
```

and on window **load** you can do your work:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.share_points').forEach(ele => getActivityPoint(ele, ap[ele.dataset.load]));
});
function getActivityPoint(ele, activityName) {
    ele.textContent = activityName;
}

var ap = {
    'movie_review':'20',
    'game_review': 10
}

/****************
 For Compatibility issue you may write:

window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
            Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.share_points')).forEach(function (ele) {
      getActivityPoint(ele, ap[ele.dataset.load]);
   });
});

For IE < 9 the solution is:

 window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.share_points');
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      getActivityPoint(divs[i], ap[divs[i].dataset.load]);
  }
});
        
*/
```

```html
<div class="share_points" data-load="movie_review">-</div>
<div class="share_points" data-load="game_review">-</div>
```

Comment: Are all browsers equal?

Comment: @Xotic750 no not at all but I am just trying to add the value from variable to html element. and it should be there at for all browsers.

Comment: @Xotic750 No not all. I don't care that below 9.

Comment: I personally don't even care for IE11 support, but IE<9 doesn't have support for `addEventListener`, IE<8 doesn't support `querySelectorAll` and `dataset` is not supported below IE11 :)

Comment: Guys Please suggest which one should I use ? 1st, 2nd or 3rd  solution ? dataset not working in ie9 and ie10 ? should I use the first one ?

Comment: You may use getattribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
var ap = {
      'movie_review': '20',
      'game_review': '100'
    },
    share_points = document.getElementsByClassName('share_points');

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(share_points, function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = ap[el.dataset.review];
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="share_points" data-review="movie_review">-</div>
<div class="share_points" data-review="game_review">-</div>
```

Comment: so for next I have to do ` share_points[1].innerHTML = ap.game_review;` ?

Comment: Yes.. I am improving my answer to make it more dynamic.. @gaetanoM is a better answer

Comment: Improved answer

Comment: Thanks for your effort but I guess this code will not run over all browsers. That arrow `=>` might be buggy. don't you think ?